# Run JavaScript immediately but wait x seconds before it can be run again?

Tags: javascript

Im listening for an event and I need to run a function (in this example console log for demoing my code) when it happens.

This is working however the event happens multiple times in quick succession and I only want the function to run once. How can I run the function straight away but then wait a second before its able to be triggered again?

```
  $(document).on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
    if (var === 'something') {
      console.log('Run');
    }
  });
```

Update: To be clear, I need to wait for the event 'someEvent' to occur before my console function runs.

Comment: first-to-run sets a flag and a timeout. subsequent calls check for that flag, and simply bail out if it's set. when the timeout expires, it can clear the flag and do another call.

Comment: Perhaps set a toggle variable and execute a `setTimeout` that toggles the variable 1000 ms later.  Have your function only execute if the toggle holds the desired value.

Comment: Do you have a more complete sample with fiddle or codepen in order to see the case

Comment: Have a look at lodash's throttle. You can imitate it with native code as well

Answer (score 1):

Some like that?

```
var is_blocked = false;

var block = function( time_to_wait ) {
    is_blocked = true;

    setTimeout( function() {
        is_blocked = false;
    }, time_to_wait );
};

$(document).on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
    if ( is_blocked === false ) {
        block( 1000 );
        console.log('Run');
    }
});
```

Comment: This doenst seem to work for me. Do you have a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Function "functionToBeCalled()" will be executed immediately, and every 0.4 seconds. If you want to call again that function after 0.4s and not every time replace setInterval with setTimeout.

```js
var variable = "something";

 $("#button").on('click', function(event, data) {
    if ( variable === 'something') {
      console.log('Run');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#button").trigger("click");
      }, 1000)
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to run the function over and over again. Just wants a 'cooldown' time

Comment: I need to wait for the event 'someEvent' in my example.

Comment: @jdln I have edited the code above, it will wait for button to click if it is clicked after 1 second it will trigger again

Comment: I dont think you've understood what I need. I need the console to log straight away, but even if you keep clicking the trigger it wont log again untill 1 second has passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an external library, use [lodash's debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) method. Note that the sample in the docs is pretty similar to the case you described. The options (leading/trailing) can be used to customize the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the current time:

```
var waitUntil = Date.now();

$(document).on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
    if (Date.now() >= waitUntil) {
        waitUntil = Date.now() + 5000 // 5 seconds wait from now
        console.log('Run');
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL03nbm9/) which uses a button click as the event, and gives feed-back on-screen about whether the event is treated or not.

Comment: Will this wait 5 seconds to execute the console log? This isnt what I need. I need the console function to run immediately, but then to not be triggerable again for 5 second.

Comment: No, this runs immediately on the first occurrence of the event: the first time the `if` is encountered the condition is true (any time is greater than 0). Then it sets the boundary time to now+5seconds. If the event occurs before that time expires, the condition will be false.

Comment: I have added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL03nbm9/) so you can see more visually that it works. The fiddle uses a button click as the event. First click always executes the `console.log`, then it will not work for 5 seconds, ... etc

Answer (score 0):

There's a tiny library called [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) that has a ton of useful functions. Among these there is [`_.debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

> `debounce_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])`
>
> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function
>   which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have
>   elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing
>   behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving.
>   For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating
>   a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.
>
> Pass true for the immediate argument to cause debounce to trigger the
>   function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the wait
>   interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental
>   double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time.

In your case it's a matter of wrapping the handler function like this (I used 100ms for the timeout):

```
$(document).on('someEvent', _.debounce(function(event, data) {
  if (var === 'something') {
    console.log('Run');
  }
}, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat little function that might help:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```